# Tables with MD_ prefix were found in my Oracle DB - is there any info about them?

Tags: oracle

Recently, during up-gradation of my Oracle DB, I have found many tables whose names are starting with `MD_`, which are empty.

- Is there any info about them?
- Can I drop them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559835/any-idea-about-these-extra-tables-in-my-development-schema

Answer (score 1):

These tables use for Migration workbench.
Please see this [link](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/models/MInfo.html) for more information